# Which all fonts are supported by Flutter without requiring external import?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Text(
    'Sample',
    style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: '',
    ), // TextStyle
), //Text
```

What all values can I give to the fontFamily attribute without downloading external fonts ?

Comment: Good question. Where is the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Having looked at [`material/typography.dart`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/typography.dart) you should be able to find out:

For Android and default to `MaterialApp`

The default font of MaterialApp is [roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto), a Google font.

```
 /// A material design text theme with dark glyphs based on Roboto.
  ///
  /// This [TextTheme] provides color but not geometry (font size, weight, etc).
  static const TextTheme blackMountainView = TextTheme(
    display4   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView display4',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black54, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display3   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView display3',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black54, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display2   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView display2',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black54, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display1   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView display1',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black54, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    headline   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView headline',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    title      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView title',      fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    subhead    : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView subhead',    fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    body2      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView body2',      fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    body1      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView body1',      fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    caption    : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView caption',    fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black54, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    button     : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView button',     fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    subtitle   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView subtitle',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    overline   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackMountainView overline',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.black,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
  );

  /// A material design text theme with light glyphs based on Roboto.
  ///
  /// This [TextTheme] provides color but not geometry (font size, weight, etc).
  static const TextTheme whiteMountainView = TextTheme(
    display4   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView display4',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white70, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display3   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView display3',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white70, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display2   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView display2',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white70, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display1   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView display1',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white70, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    headline   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView headline',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    title      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView title',      fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    subhead    : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView subhead',    fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    body2      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView body2',      fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    body1      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView body1',      fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    caption    : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView caption',    fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white70, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    button     : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView button',     fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    subtitle   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView subtitle',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    overline   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteMountainView overline',   fontFamily: 'Roboto', inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
  );
```

and for iOS if using `Curpertino` it would be `.SF UI Display` default ios font.

```
 /// A material design text theme with dark glyphs based on San Francisco.
  ///
  /// This [TextTheme] provides color but not geometry (font size, weight, etc).
  static const TextTheme blackCupertino = TextTheme(
    display4   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino display4',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.black54, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display3   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino display3',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.black54, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display2   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino display2',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.black54, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display1   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino display1',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.black54, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    headline   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino headline',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    title      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino title',      fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    subhead    : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino subhead',    fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    body2      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino body2',      fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    body1      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino body1',      fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    caption    : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino caption',    fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.black54, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    button     : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino button',     fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.black87, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    subtitle   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino subtitle',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.black,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    overline   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'blackCupertino overline',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.black,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
  );

  /// A material design text theme with light glyphs based on San Francisco.
  ///
  /// This [TextTheme] provides color but not geometry (font size, weight, etc).
  static const TextTheme whiteCupertino = TextTheme(
    display4   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino display4',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.white70, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display3   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino display3',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.white70, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display2   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino display2',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.white70, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    display1   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino display1',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.white70, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    headline   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino headline',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    title      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino title',      fontFamily: '.SF UI Display', inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    subhead    : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino subhead',    fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    body2      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino body2',      fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    body1      : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino body1',      fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    caption    : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino caption',    fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.white70, decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    button     : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino button',     fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    subtitle   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino subtitle',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
    overline   : TextStyle(debugLabel: 'whiteCupertino overline',   fontFamily: '.SF UI Text',    inherit: true, color: Colors.white,   decoration: TextDecoration.none),
  );
```

So, you should be able to retrieve the font family by the following code

```
DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.fontFamily
```

Therefore, you can reuse the same font as you retrieve.

Comment: This shows the default font that is used right ? I was looking for fonts that could be set to fontFamily attribute. Like we do in css without requiring external font files.

Comment: How to use font **AvenirNext** on iOS ? This font is default supported by iOS.
This my tried not work:
```
fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
fontFamily: 'AvenirNext-Regular',

Comment: this does not answer the question. How to use the fonts in the project? what fonts are available? I google searched for some fonts from this list and i found nothing related to them.